# How to consider space at the end while sorting in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8, comparator

I have a list of Strings.

```
TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ tag4
 TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID13_tag
 TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ 6th_tag
 TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag1
 TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag2
 TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag5
```

When I do

```
 List<String> test = Arrays.asList(
            "TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ tag4",
            "TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID13_tag",
            "TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ 6th_tag",
            "TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag1",
            "TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag2",

            "TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag5");
        Collections.sort(test);
        System.out.println(test);
```

output is `[TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID13_tag, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ 6th_tag, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ tag4, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag1, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag2, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag5]`

How can I get the order as 
`[TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID13_tag, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ 6th_tag, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag1, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag2,TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_ tag4, TagSort-Test-CA-ASSET-ID1_tag5]`

This is the format I get from postgres DB. I need maintain same behaviour in Java as well.

Comment: what was your attempt at it? did you get to know what patten does the postgress DB follow?

Answer (score 1):

The Postgress DB sorting looks to be removing the whitespaces, such as the following output is alike to your expected output:

```
test.stream()
    .map(s -> s.replace(" ", ""))
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But since the actual data is now mapped, you end up losing it, hence mapping the actual string as entry key and whitespace removed string as the value could work out for you as :

```
test.stream()
    .map(s -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(s, s.replace(" ", "")))
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984264/purpose-of-collate-in-postgres
Collate is the culprit for this behaviour diff

Comment: @SantoshHegde hmm, interesting, thanks for sharing, would bookmark for future references if I may need.